# Int object not iterable? (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I cant seem to find a solution anywhere, I have a script that runs a facial recognition script, but for some reason its telling me this exact error:

---

> File "box.py",line 98, in  
>              label,confidence = model.predict(crop) 
>     TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

---

My code thats actually important to  the problem:

---

```
import cv2

#Creates model to be the facerecognizer
model = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()

#Defines the model as a training image taken previously
model.load(config.TRAINING_FILE)

#Initializes the camera as camera
camera = config.get_camera()

#Takes a picture using the camera
image = camera.read()

#Converts to grayscale
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#Results if it found a face
result = face.detect_single(image)

#Tells you to keep taking a picture until you have a face recognized
if result is None:
        print 'Could not see face! Retake picture!'
        continue

 #gets dimensions of the face
 x,y,w,h = result

 #resizes the face
 crop = face.resize(face.crop(image, x, y, w, h))

 #Tests face against the previously taken model
 label, confidence = model.predict(crop) **<--- This is where the error is**

 #Im not 100% as to what this does, I got this part on the internet
 result = cv2.face.MinDistancePredictCollector()
 model.predict(crop)
 label = result.getLabel()
 confidence = result.getDist()
```

Thats basically it (Theres obviously some more code set up inside and between but it isnt important or relevant to the issue, at least I dont think, Im using Python 2.7 with opencv 3.1.0 on a raspbian raspberry pi 3 if you need that information

Comment: **Hint:** ```a,b=5```´-> ```TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable```. I'm glad someone edited your question. The title alone would have give you so many downvotes.

Comment: a=b=5 does not give an error

Comment: What do you mean a,b = 5? is that referencing something wrong with the fact I used label, confidence?

Comment: Yes. You are unpacking something which can't be unpacked. Look what's returned by predict before unpacking to debug ```result=model.predict(crop)``` and ```print(result)```. You either misinterpret the docs or opencv's python-wrappers are broken or not following the C++ API. [Maybe relevant A](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/512) and [B](https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3/issues/11) (but i won't do that research for you; maybe someone else will)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling you that `model.predict(crop)` only returns one thing, and you're telling Python to expect it to return two things.

However, unless you omitted some important stuff, it looks like you overwrite the variables `label` and `confidence` in the next code block, so you could ostensibly just remove that line of code.

If you can't remove that line, then make a hotfix by setting one of those variables to zero: `label, confidence = model.predict(crop), 0`

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly the answer that I was wanting

Comment: Happy to help! (by the way, you can reward me with valueless internet points by marking my answer correct with the green check mark :)